# Get Paginator Previous to add another parameter

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.2, paginator

How do I get this:

```
 echo '<td>'.$paginator->prev('Previous', array($query_encode)).'</td>';
```

to have another parameter in the url?

Comment: theres nothing in the api, without doing some kind of hack i don't think it's possibly that easy

Comment: you are wrong. Follow the links in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Pagination for custom queries](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/shird10/2010/08/29/pagination-for-custom-queries) article and at [Pagination in Views](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1233/Pagination-in-Views) in the manual.